# How to return a text of an element if it's displayed

Tags: c#, selenium

I want to find some elements on alternative airport prices. Now there are some prices which are not displayed so what I am trying to do is only get the text for the first displayed airport price.

So I am trying to do a foreach loop where it looks through the alternative airport prices. Once a airport price is displayed, break out form the loop and simply return the text of this price.

The problem is I am struggling to implement the `alternativeAirportPrice.Text;` and returning it. I want to ask how to implement this.

```
    public void GetAlternativeAirportPrice(By airportPriceLocator)
    {
        var alternativeAirportPrices = _driver.FindElements(airportPriceLocator);

        foreach (var alternativeAirportPrice in alternativeAirportPrices)
        {
            if (alternativeAirportPrice.Displayed)
                return alternativeAirportPrice.Text;
                break;

        }
        return alternativeAirportPrice.Text;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably just want:

```
public string GetAlternativeAirportPrice(By airportPriceLocator)
{
    var alternativeAirportPrices = _driver.FindElements(airportPriceLocator);

    foreach (var alternativeAirportPrice in alternativeAirportPrices)
    {
        if (alternativeAirportPrice.Displayed)
            return alternativeAirportPrice.Text;
    }

    return null;
}
```

, removing your `break`, as that will cause your `foreach` to exit after the first element if you didn't find a displayed price.

After you find a price and `return` it you don't need the `break`.

Also notice that you need a return type to your function, I suppose your `alternativeAirportPrice.Text` is a `string`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was close. I should have tried it with a public string